# How to fill Nested Data with DataGrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid, desktop-application

I want to fill nested data in dataGrid columns in wpf and I have attach main class model with datagrid itemsource so I don't know how to use and fill that details inside it.

### Models :

```
public class SESSION
{
    public string open { get; set; }
    public string high { get; set; }
    public string low { get; set; }
    public string last { get; set; }
}

public class QUOTE
{
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<SESSION> SESSION { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<QUOTE> QUOTE { get; set; }
}
```

and my datagrid is in xaml file is :

```
 <DataGrid Name="grdData">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding name}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Symbol" Binding="{Binding symbol}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="High" Binding="{Binding high}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Low" Binding="{Binding low}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

Also I am using  grdData.ItemsSource = rootObject.QUOTE.ToList(); for fill data in gridview.
So How can I fetch open, high, low and last value from session in DataGrid ?

Please help to solve this one.

Comment: SESSION is a List - how do you expect the grid to be layed out? you could use a `<DataGridTemplateColumn>` and use a DataTemplate to display the SESSION items. Or, if SESSION only contains one item, bind to the first record in the collection, e.g. `<DataGridTextColumn Header="High" Binding="{Binding Path=SESSION[0].high}" />`

Comment: Hi Simon. I have applied `SESSION[0].high` but it's not returning any thing.

Comment: Does it definitely contain a value? I have created a test project and works well for me with test data. I'll post as an answer so you can see code...

Answer (score 0):

As the SESSION property is a list, you either need to use another collection control, e.g. ItemsControl, in a DataGridTemplateColumn, or bind to a specific item in the list. Going with the latter, from the comments, I have a test window as follows:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CoSecApp_v3"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="TestWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="grdData" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding name}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Symbol" Binding="{Binding symbol}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="High" Binding="{Binding Path=SESSION[0].high}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Low" Binding="{Binding Path=SESSION[0].low}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
public class TestWindow
{
private void TestWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RootObject DC = new RootObject();
    DC.QUOTE = new List<QUOTE>();
    for (int I = 1; I <= 10; I++)
    {
        DC.QUOTE.Add(new QUOTE() { name = "Name" + I, symbol = I, SESSION = new List<SESSION>() });
        DC.QUOTE[I - 1].SESSION.Add(new SESSION() { open = "open", high = "100", low = "10", last = "final" });
    }
    grdData.ItemsSource = DC.QUOTE.ToList();
}

public class SESSION
{
    public string open { get; set; }
    public string high { get; set; }
    public string low { get; set; }
    public string last { get; set; }
}

public class QUOTE
{
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<SESSION> SESSION { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<QUOTE> QUOTE { get; set; }
}
}
```

This populates my grid with the test data as expected.

(BTW do not think .ToList is necessary on `DC.QUOTE.ToList()` as it is already a List object.)